# simple Java api to form and send ntp packet

Tags: java, netty, ntp

We should feed some system under test with ntp data, that we should control. Since the testing environment is mainly java-oriented, it would be perfect to find and reuse any java code, that forms and send ntp packets. There is no matter, how precise this server side would be, since the main idea of the test to provide the mocked time through via ntp packets. Is there any ntp java library, or may be example, especially for netty usage?

I would appreciate for any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

UPD. Since the question is taken to 'on hold' (I don't understand why, ntp + java seems to be too familiar to local folks, but not to me), I'd like to summarize it to simple question:

Is there Java API that can provide ntp server packets on ntp client dmand being simple like NTPPacket ntpp=new NTPPacket(new Time()); while all other wirings will be default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ho-ho, I see some haters already started their downvotes; it seems they just see the title, but not the details of the issues (I really dislike this kind of haters)

I have even to remove 'java' tag here. So, my suggestion that I can reuse http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.server/apacheds-protocol-ntp/2.0.0-M15 for this purpose